# Is it possible, how to show diff between commits in github?

Tags: github

A user proposed a localization to an open source project; however, they proposed a localization for an old version. I'd like to point them at the changes that were made between the two.

I know that I can show the difference between branches by providing the following link:

```
https://github.com/<user or organization>/<project>/master...master:<branch name>
```

Is there a similar interface for comparing certain commits? (and, ideally, only versions of a certain file) I'd like not to bother the potential contributor with learning git and doing the diff locally in the first place (although that I'll suggest that in the future).

I've tried

```
https://github.com/<user or organization>/<project>/master...master:<hash>
```

but that didn't work which is kinda expected; and I haven't found any reference on this matter either.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can compare the difference between two commits on GitHub by using the below URL

```
https://github.com/{user}/{repo}/compare/{commit-1-hash}..{commit-2-hash}
```

For eg, to compare the diff between commits `c3a414e` and `faf7c6f` for the `linguist` repo of `github`, use the below

```
https://github.com/github/linguist/compare/c3a414e..faf7c6f
```

The above will show the diff like this:

[image]

You can go through the GitHub [reference](https://help.github.com/en/github/committing-changes-to-your-project/comparing-commits#comparing-commits) for more information.

Comment: Yes, it does answer the question, although I have to admit direct comparison shows too many files. Are you aware of the way to show diff for a certain file, like with `-- filename` in git?

Comment: On the other hand, that page has anchors like `#diff-7a561b51e29616a48bfa2eccdc3a9360` for each file so may be this is good enough